# Continuous and differential inverse function

Tags: differential, inverse-function, continuity

I have a very interesting question:

> Given a function $f$ which is continuous but need not be differentiable.
>   Then the correct statement is
>   **a.** it can be an odd function
>   **b.** it can't be an invertible function
>   **c.** it can be an invertible function

By just examining $f(x) = x$ it is an odd function which is differentiable.
I rule out **a.**

Also $\mod x$ is not be invertible and not differentiable.
So somehow I believe that the answer should be **b.**

Basically what should be my approach?

What is the proper way of examining this type of question?

Also is there any relationship between differentiable and invertible functions?

Thank you.

Comment: As to your last question, this might be interesting to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem  Basically, if a function is differentiable, has continuous derivative, and its derivative at a point is not zero (for the multivariable case, doesn't have zero determinant), then it is invertible sufficiently close to the given point. Consider the function $f(x)=x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

a) f could be a triangle wave -- odd, continuous, not-differentiable.

b) or c) must be true.  So which is it?

A bijective function is invertable.  Can you come up with a bijection that is continuous but not differentiable?

$f(x) = \begin{cases} x&x<0\\2x &x\ge0\end{cases}$